# wp8 C# browser freezing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm back to implement a code, but something is going wrong. 
Simply by browsing the web, the browser freezes, locking the cell and preventing its closure. What is he missing? 
Help me please! 
The code I use is exactly this:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private const int NumTabs = 10;

    private int currentIndex;
    private string[] urls = new string[NumTabs];
    private WebBrowser[] browsers = new WebBrowser[NumTabs];

    public MainPage()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    ShowTab(0);
 }

 private void ShowTab(int index)
 {
    this.currentIndex = index;
    UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "";
    if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser;
        BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++)
    {
        if (this.browsers[i] != null)
        {
            this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}

private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        Uri url;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
        {
            this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
            this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid url");
    }
 }

 private void TabMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int index = Int32.Parse(((ApplicationBarMenuItem)sender).Text) - 1;
    ShowTab(index);
 }
}
```

Comment: It's like he went into an infinite loop...

Answer (score -1):

You only have one for loop to determine if this is causing the problem then comment it out and loop and run the app. If it is causing the problem then either put it in a try catch  of after 10 loop break the loop.

Comment: Do you think is the NumTabs with value 10 which is causing a Loop.
`private const int NumTabs = 10;`
Could you tell me how to do it, because I'm new to this subject. I thank you